# CHIRP on Mac in 2021

Tags: chirp, macos

Has anybody had success in running CHIRP on a modern Mac? I am running OSX 10.15.7 and the download I found for Mac looks like just source code, no app file at all. I'm considering trying a build from source code, but before I get into that let me ask, has anyone got this working?

Comment: It seems surprising that someone wouldn't package an application as popular as Chirp, but I'm not a Mac user.  Do fewer hams choose Macs, proportionally, than the general population of computer users, I wonder?

Comment: @rclocher3 Open source software isn't likely to pay the $99/year to maintain an Apple Developer Account and the rights to code-sign an installer, which is what an app that requires hardware device drivers (a much higher security risk than a strictly-user-land app) must have. Security and convenience aren't friends. :-)

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi on Linux and Windows CHIRP includes no hardware drivers; the user just points the software at an existing serial port, whether it be an old-school DE-9 jack or a virtual USB serial port.

Comment: Manufacturers often make auto-discoverable drivers for Windows, leaving the OSS community to reverse-engineer divers for other platforms. “Windows is configuring your device…”

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi whether that fee is a security feature or simply anticompetitive behavior is [up for debate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2021/04/30/epic-apple-trial-antitrust-fortnite-app-store/).

Comment: Sure. I’m an Apple user but I’m not a fan boy and find such debates to be of limited use in technical discussions. Of course I have opinions both as a user and as a once-indie software developer, but my feelings are not facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ... complicated. You indicated macOS 10.15, which adds a ton of strict security pertaining to just what third-party apps are allowed to do. The download page on the [CHIRP website](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home) has a link for [macOS downloads](https://trac.chirp.danplanet.com/chirp_daily/LATEST/). The download list highlights the recommended download in green (the "unified daily app" build). Just beneath that, the "**Confused about what to download?**" heading states this is the correct choice. Download that and unzip it and there's the built app.

But wait! There's more!

That same "confused" point about macOS links to a [macOS-specific tips](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/MacOS_Tips#Application-Security-in-MacOS-1015-Catalina) page. This page mentions two things to consider:

1. The app security measures I mentioned above means you'll likely have to grant whole-disk access to the app in order to be able to be able to open certain data files you'll need to open (since this is not a signed app).
2. You'll also need to install a driver specific to the kind of USB adaptor cable you're using. Again due to macOS security, an unsigned app can't go through the blessed security gate, so can't get the correct access to install and load any old device drivers.

Give that tips page a thorough read (there's even a troubleshooting section). It's not the prettiest getting-started process but it's open-source software that's maintained to be multi-platform, so it's not going to be a particularly smooth ride for any one platform. Except maybe for Windows, which most ham software targets. Even then, it's often bumpy due to the age of some of these apps.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, it is pretty complicated. i plan to give this a go and report back.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The security rigamarole is familiar to me and after I got the right thing into my /Application folder and installed the FTDI cable driver, I am now able to at least connect to the UV-5R. Now to figure out what the heck I'm looking at. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A friend bought an M1 Mini and is having trouble. Asked me to download Chirp from https://trac.chirp.danplanet.com/chirp_daily/LATEST/

chirp-unified-daily-20210704.app.zip runs on my 2013 MacPro with 11.4. Or at least "it looks to me like it runs" as I haven't tried to run it through its paces.

To override the lack of a developer signing key open the app with right mouse click then "Open". It won't bother you again.

Says it is a "unified" app but failed on my friend's M1 but he has only had a Mac for 36 hours.

Comment: I think that the new non-intel chips is going to be a problem on the newest Macs.