# Can't run CHIRP on macOS Monterey (12.4)

Tags: software, chirp, macos

I'm unable to install both the precompiled binary and the brew cask versions of CHIRP on macOS 12.4. The issues do not seem to be covered by [this](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/18617/chirp-on-mac-in-2021) similar question composed by a macOS 10.x user.

After getting the binary passed security the app just immediately crashes anytime you attempt to run it. I have an Apple cash report available if that's helpful. For the `brew` version, it's currently choking on a reference to `pygtk` which can't be found.

```
==> Tapping tdsmith/ham
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/tdsmith/homebrew-ham'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 65, done.
remote: Total 65 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 65
Unpacking objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Tapped 3 formulae (79 files, 37.9KB).
Warning: No available formula with the name "pygtk" (dependency of tdsmith/ham/chirp). Did you mean pygitup?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
This similarly named formula was found:
pygitup
To install it, run:
  brew install pygitup
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: This seems like a question better posed to the authors of CHIRP.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer What, are they too good to use StackExchange? Jk. I noticed that there were a lot of CHIRP questions and it's considered on-topic but yes I will open a GitHub issue or something if we can't get it answered here.

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask CHIRP questions... but this really seems to be more of a "I can't get this to install on my system," which isn't really a radio question.  It's just my opinion.  Folks might be able to help you here, but the project owners seem better positioned.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Most likely I will self-answer. It's a dependency issue, probably `pygtk` isn't ready for newer macOS. I will dig into it after work.

Comment: If your Mac is an M1 / Apple Silicon (which is ARM), the package may not be available yet. You may need to build some or all from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:
You must install the deprecated Python Version 2.7

You can find the installer here:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18-macosx10.9.pkg

I tested this on an Intel Mac running Monterey 12.4

73's

Eric (N6LG)

Comment: Good answer, but Python 2 oy vey

Comment: @Hack-R, I empathasize withyou and the chirp crew hopefuly will upgrade. That said, Mac end users really need a solution  now.   I don't know Python well enough to offer a pull request update to their repo.